# Driving directions between 40 markers. (Source, Destination and 38 waypoints). Is it possible?

Tags: google-maps

I need to be able to add 40 markers (places I visited) and show the
route I followed through them by car. How do I do this? Whatever I
have read so far makes me believe that one can only show such driving
directions between a maximum of 25 markers. I feel the limitation is
cause the markers are named as A....Z. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the maximum number of waypoints is 8. If you include the origin and destination that means you can only use 10 points.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsWaypoint

You could string multiple requests together and use a custom marker image.